# PrimeNg dropdown in tree-table auto scroll based on dropdown in the bottom of the page

Tags: angular6, primeng, primeng-treetable

I am implementing dropdown in primeng treetable and bottom of the page the dropdown is hiding below the panel. How can make it auto adjust. Scroll automatically and so that user can see the dropdown.

Note:
Table is wrapped with bootstrap pannel.

Comment: Actually i figure it out by add a property to <p -dropdown> , appendTo="body". That is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
<p-dropdown appendTo="body"> </p-dropdown>
```

It works for me